# PyQt5 Unable to clear a field using InputMask

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am having an issue with a QLineEdit on a QTableView on which I have placed an input mask.  The problem I am running into is I cannot clear the field once a value has been placed into it.  Removing the inputmask allows me to clear the field.  My code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class PhnDataModel(QStandardItemModel):    
    sig_loaded = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PhnDataModel, self).__init__(parent)

    def newItem(self, xpos, ypos, display, data=None):
        item = QStandardItem()
        item.setData(display, Qt.DisplayRole)
        if data != None:
            item.setData(data, Qt.UserRole)
        self.setItem(xpos, ypos, item)

    def loadModel(self):
        self.clear()
        for ndx in range(4):
            self.newItem(ndx, 1, ["Office", "Fax", "Mobile", "Other"][ndx], ndx)
            self.newItem(ndx, 0, "")
            self.newItem(ndx, 2, "")
        self.sig_loaded.emit()

class PhnDataDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(PhnDataDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)
        if index.column() == 2:
            option.text = index.data()
            option.displayAlignment = Qt.AlignVCenter | Qt.AlignHCenter

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if index.column() == 1:
            option.font.setWeight(QFont.Bold)
            option.palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, QColor(0, 51, 0))
        QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        if index.column() == 2:
            editor = QLineEdit(parent)
            editor.setInputMask("(999) 999-9999")
            return editor
        QStyledItemDelegate.createEditor(self, parent, option, index)


class PhnDataBrowse(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PhnDataBrowse, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(QRect(5, 5, 286, 111))
        self.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)
        self.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.setCornerButtonEnabled(False)
        self.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.model = PhnDataModel()
        self.model.sig_loaded.connect(self.__loaded)
        self.setItemDelegate(PhnDataDelegate())

    def __loaded(self):
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.setColumnHidden(0, True)
        self.resizeRowsToContents()
        self.selectRow(0)


class testWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(testWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.phndata = PhnDataBrowse()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.phndata)
        self.save_btn = QPushButton()
        self.save_btn.setText("Save")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.save_btn)            
        self.phndata.model.loadModel()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = testWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Looks as if the inputMask expects the field to be non-blank or zero.  How do I get around this obstacle?

Comment: you generate several errors, could you test your **[MCVE]**?

Comment: you could also better explain your question, what do you mean by *clear a field using InputMask*?

Comment: Yeah, code is fixed - copied the wrong panel over.  Run the code, double click to enter a phone number.  Once the phone number is entered according to the mask, re-edit the phone number and try to remove it.

Comment: okay, you want to delete the phone number so I know how to start

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Your description in your previous comment is better than the explanation in your question, I think you should add it to your question

Comment: A consultation, when the complete telephone number is not entered, the previous text is not modified. Do you think that behavior will be maintained?

Comment: Looks like the problem I am having is using (999) 999-9999 instead of (000) 000-0000.  Poblem is fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the problem I am having is using (999) 999-9999 instead of (000) 000-0000. Poblem is fixed.